# Android: Caching images for imageView

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android app which calls codeline B many times.

Therefore I would like to cache the image 'image123' somewhere for performance reasons / making the app faster and only want to load it once and then just display it from the cache somehow.

Is there a way to achieve this without loading it again and again? Does anybody know ?

Is it important to call invalidate() (codeline C) just to be sure the image is always displayed immediately ? How can I find out when the image is displayed in the imageView exactly ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
// codeline A
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
// codeline B
imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image123);
// codeline C
imageView.invalidate();
```

Comment: You can use a svg image file for such use. Svg's are loaded when they are first used and then used every time with that cache.

Comment: Thanks code-crusher for your help. Is there a tutorial or an example for using svg images ?

Comment: just convert your images to vector images. Those will be .xml files. Put them into _drawable_ folder. Just apply them as you do to .png files( @drawable/my_svg) :)

Comment: When I convert .png images to vector images, then they are .svg images. These images aren't allowed by the imageView. How can I convert them to .xml images ?

Comment: try this http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ . Haven't tried it myself as it use material design svg(they are already present) and not custom.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this without loading it again and again?

There is an official tutorial for that: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

> Is it important to call invalidate() (codeline C) just to be sure the image is always displayed immediately ?

No, just setting a new image resource will automatically lead to a redraw.

> How can I find out when the image is displayed in the imageView exactly ?

Use [`View.post`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) to run code as soon as drawing is finished.

Comment: Thanks F43nd1r for your answer. 

Is there an easier way to store an image in a Drawable for example when starting the app and then just displaying it everytime from the cache or must I follow all the steps from the cache-bitmap tutorial you mentioned ? 

How can I use the post method from View exactly ?

Comment: An easier way is to not cache bitmaps yourself, which is the normal practice. You should call view.post with a Runnable which does whatever you want to do after the image is displayed.